How to access Payload after accessing the Request url
Through Selenium in the Python language, I am working on testing the website, and I was able to access the link for the Request, and I want to access the Payload. Attached is an image that shows
enter image description here
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

driver.get("https://www.example.com")

network_entries = driver.execute_script(
    "return window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource');")

       
for entry in network_entries:
    target_url = entry['name']
    if("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open" in target_url):
        

        print("URL:", target_url)
        # need print payload !!
        #print("PAYLOAD:", payload)

I want to access and print what is in the payload ,, As in the attached picture –

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to access and print what is in the payload ,, As in the attached picture

I think you are using GET Request.
-> use driver.post("https://www.example.com")

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
